# Is it a good idea to test redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs

Project that I'm working on is written in such pattern: each component has index.js with redux mappings and page.js which accepts mappings via props and renders a view.

Component can be huge, it can contain long chains of other smaller components.
Imagine how each component in the chain accepts around 30 props - redux data and redux actions - and then pass them into other components via chain, other components pass them into another components.

Though it's very typical redux situation, I can't live with it and trying to avoid it all the time. I'm trying to use `useSelector` and `useDispatch` to work with store, instead of passing dozens of properties I add `useSelector` right in the place where data is needed.

And all seems to be fine except tests.

I wrote utils for test to mount components inside redux Provider, utils to easily mutate store and to check history of dispatch.
But tests feels more complicated now then before when they just passed props.

It feels that I'm the only person who tries to write tests using redux store.
Is it good idea or bad? Do you know some articles of how to use `useSelector` and `useDispatch` and write tests at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

For testability, look into the Container & Presentation Component Pattern. What you basically do is create a component that is purely presentational and maintains next to no state. Everything it displays, it'll get via props. This will let you test the visual elements without worrying about the store.

Next, create a container component that does all of the redux stuff, e.g., fetches, dispatches, etc. and it'll pass the relevant state as props to the presentational component. This will keep your test file size in check and allow you to focus your tests towards different goals while keeping them much simpler. So, your directory will look something like,

coolComponent

- coolComponent.js (presentational component)
- coolComponent.test.js
- index.js (container component)
- index.test.js

Testing the store is important as the store and redux determines your data flow. If your data flow doesn't work, it doesn't matter if you have 1000 tests passing elsewhere. You app will fail.

Keep in mind when testing the components that sometimes it doesn't make sense to test the components on their own. If they're only ever used with a parent, I think you can get good coverage testing them with the parent, so don't double your efforts going overboard with testing that way.

Comment: FYI, this is *not* the Higher Order Component Pattern, but rather the Container & Presentation Component Pattern (*sometimes called Smart & Dumb components*). HOCs are functions that consume a component and return a (presumably augmented) component whereas a container component simply wraps and proxies data to the props of a presentational component, i.e. they are just wrapper components. https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Comment: @DrewReese I always thought about it in function terms. Since it returns a component (a function), it would be considered h/o. Thanks for the clarification. Now I have to go apologize to everyone I know for telling them the wrong thing. :)

Comment: But I said that project already use this pattern in first sentence of question, or my first sentence was not clean?

The problem which I have with this patter is that container passed around 30 props to presentational component, that presentational component passed all or almost all of those props next to children components who also want to work with store. And there are dozens of such components in a project.

So this is correct redux architecture and we just need to live with it when project use redux.

Comment: @user2541867 it's not made obvious. You can put all of the code in a single file, call it index and use redux with it.